# Getting error when sending image as a prop in React Native

Tags: react-native

### This is the error:

TransformError app/components/search/Repository.js: app/components/search/Repository.js:Invalid call at line 12: require("" + image)

### This is my code:

```
export default function Repository({ title, subTitle, image, onPress }) {
  console.log(image);
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.light} onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require(`${image}`)}></Image>
        <View style={styles.details}>
          <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

The prop "image" is a string which contains a path to my image in the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

Normally in react you import the image at the top of the file.

```
import Image from "../path/to/img.png"
```

Then later

```
<Image src={Image}/>
```

Comment: I am passing the image as a prop and not importing it in React Native.